# Filter First Column Text File (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

Newbie to PowerShell. 
I want to filter in column 1 where value in a text file equal "Find"

```
    Get-Content -Path C:\home\file.csv | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Find"
```

When I ran the above script it returns all records in column 1 that equal "Find" and other columns that have "Find", it should only return column 1 where value is "Find"

Please can you help?

Comment: Why don't you use Import-csv instead of Get-Content?

Comment: This works. How do I export result to csv. Out-File maintains the same staggered format but not comma seperated

Answer (score 3):

Use Import-csv:

```
Import-Csv C:\home\file.csv -Header Col1,Col2,Col3 | Select-Object -Unique Col1 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Find"
```

Adjust the header columns to the columns you have. I assume you have no headers in the csv. otherwise it would be even easier.

Comment: I was about to write that, but you already gave that answer.Good call mate